# Create a helix in matlab

Tags: matlab, helix

i am finding it difficult to Create a helix with radius 2, which makes one revolution in the xy-plane and moves one unit in z-direction in the same time.I have used something like this [pos,mag]=helix(2,1,1,30,0.25) but nothing is coming out. Is there a simple program or code for this?

Comment: I think that this is not really a programming question. The fantastic thing with programming is exactly like this. You have something that you want to achieve. Then to find a way to do this you need to sit down and think of a way to solve the problem. Often (and specially in matlab) the best solutions require some kind of mathematical solutions, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in function to do that. You need to code it yourself. Check the symbolic equation of a helix [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html):

The equations are as follow:

[image]

So you can do  this:

```
t=0:pi/50:2*pi;   % to have one complete round
r = 2;            % radius
h = 1;            % height
x = r * sin(t);
y = r * cos(t);
z = h/(2*pi) * t;   
plot3(x,y,z)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks buddy. you have opened my mind now

Comment: @Jesuit if this answer works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.